# Will installing NTFS Driver for Mac OS delete my existing files?

Tags: hard-drive, mac, drivers, ntfs

I have been saving all my PC files onto a Seagate GoFlex external hard-drive.  I am now using a Mac.  Although I can read my files, I cannot save changes.  I have been advised to install  NTFS Driver for Mac OS but am reluctant to do it until I hear from someone who has done this successfully.  My great fear is to lose all my existing files!

Thank you in advance for any help on this matter.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for any particular implementation of NTFS for Mac, personally I use Paragon & that's always been OK for me.

Essentially it just enables write for NTFS.
Mac can already read NTFS perfectly well [& can be persuaded to write with some tweaking, without adding a 3rd party solution, but is unsupported]

Adding write support should not affect your existing NTFS partitions at all.

Answer (score 1):

Just thought i would advise that i did already have NTFS for Mac installed but it must have been old or something - Honestly not sure. 
Anyway i was having the same issue - had tried everything else to try and fix the issue and get my hard drive to show up. Mine was showing in utilities but it was greyed out.

Anyways i unplugged by hard drive and installed the new NTFS for mac -http://www.seagate.com/au/en/support/downloads/item/ntfs-driver-for-mac-os-master-dl/

Now my hard drive shows up fine and no data lost or anything - Hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using OS X El Capitan, not  macOS Sierra.

I used the method outlined by the below blog post back when my Mac Book Pro had OS X Mavericks. The NTFS writing has worked with no issues, on Yosemite and El Capitan. I also recommended the below to a friend using El Capitan and it worked for them as well.

Note: I have not updated my Mac to macOS Sierra just yet, so I cannot confirm if this continues to work for Sierra and the author has not updated their post, like they did for El Capitan.

http://www.macbreaker.com/2014/06/how-to-enable-writing-to-ntfs-hard.html

As websites can go down, I'll outline the steps mentioned in the post:

1. Install FUSE for OS X [FUSE for OS X](http://osxfuse.github.io/) `(While installing FUSE for OS X, be sure to check the "MacFUSE Compatibility Layer" option in the installer.)`
2. Install NTFS-3G [NTFS-3G](http://macntfs-3g.blogspot.com/2010/10/ntfs-3g-for-mac-os-x-2010102.html) `(During the installation process, you'll be given an option to install the NTFS-3G driver with either "No caching" or "UBLIO caching". While it probably won't actually matter, you may want to choose "No caching" to be safe. Either way, can always change this setting afterwards.)`
3. Then, once the installation [of NTFS-3G] is finished, reboot your computer.
4. Install fuse-wait [fuse_wait](https://github.com/bfleischer/fuse_wait/downloads)

As the author mentions for El Capitan:

> Yes, this still works on OS X El Capitan! You may have to update OSXFuse, but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Install Seagate https://www.seagate.com/sg/en/support/downloads/item/ntfs-driver-for-mac-os-master-dl/ for seagate external drives. Works great.

Comment: what does it do?

Comment: It is a driver and transparently activate write permission for your NTFS external hard drive on Mac. Else, you won't be able to write anything on external disk.